# timer decrement and increment at the same time using c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    if (a == 0 || a < 9)
    {
        a++;
        Label1.Content = a.ToString();
    }
    else if (a >= 9 || a > 9)
    {
        a--;
        Label1.Content = a.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help. I want to increment up to 10 then if i reach 10 it will decrement down to 0 like a loop.

Comment: Was this meant to be an exclusive OR? `(a >= 9 || a > 9)`

Comment: Edit your question to include a description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways to do it, you could use :-

```
Queue<int> queue =
   new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Concat(Enumerable.Range(2, 8).Reverse()));

private void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    var a = queue.Dequeue();
    Label1.Content = a.ToString();
    queue.Enqueue(a);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. It works according to how i want it to work. Thank you very much. Gonna study more to find out how it happened LOL.

Answer (score 2):

The following can be a sample:

```
    int n = 1;
    int increase = 1;
    private void dt_Tick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (n > 9 || n < 1)
            increase *= -1;
        n += increase;
        Label1.Content = n.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If overall tick count is important, or a continuous function is required... a form of triangle wave ranging between 0 and 1 with period 2 is given by

[Triangle wave range 0-1, period 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpXT3.gif)
(6)
(Trott 2004, p. 228), where nint(x) is the nearest integer function.

ie. Triangle wave ranging between 0 and 10 with period 20 is given by

[Triangle wave range 0-10, period 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEm2i.jpg)

```
ticks++;
var a = 10 - 20 * Math.Abs(Math.Round(((ticks + 10) / 20) - ((ticks + 10) / 20));
```

For any interval (same):

```
ticks = ticks + 0.25;
var a = 10 - 20 * Math.Abs(Math.Round(((ticks + 10) / 20) - ((ticks + 10) / 20));
```

mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleWave.html